# How to refer to the iterator within the find_if predicate?

Tags: iterator, c++

I want to make sure a string has at least one alpha. Simple:

```
if ( find_if(field_name.begin(), field_name.end(), isalpha) == field_name.end() )
```

But I want to use a `locale`. I know I can easily write a separate function but I'd prefer to use it within the find_if. I.e.,

```
include <locale>

std::locale loc;

if ( find_if(field_name.begin(), field_name.end(), isalpha(*this_iterator,loc) == field_name.end() )
```

Question: Is there someway to make `this_iterator` refer to the then-current iterator?

Comment: You could probably do a `std::bind` since `*this_iterator` is passed in anyway (as it is to the first example). `std::bind(isalpha, std::placeholders::_1, loc)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11 you can do this with a lambda as Timo suggests, or with [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), as in `std::bind(isalpha, std::placeholders::_1, loc)`.

Pre-C++11, you can use [`std::bind2nd()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind2nd/) instead. This gets a bit complicated though, as it requires a `unary_function` or `binary_function` as an argument, instead of any old function object. We can create one using [`std::ptr_fun()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/ptr_fun/), although for some reason we need to explicitly tell it what the template parameters are. And we need to use `std::isalpha()` instead of `isalpha()` in order to get the locale-enabled version. So the full expression looks like

```
std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun<char, const std::locale&, bool>(std::isalpha), loc)
```

Needless to say, the C++11 version is vastly simpler.

---

BTW if you are using C++11 then you can use [`std::any_of(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) instead of `std::find_if(...) == foo.end()`. It should behave the same, but be slightly more readable.

Comment: `std::bind2nd(isalpha,loc)` gave me: "`error C2825: '_Fn2': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'`" and `std::bind2nd(isalpha(),loc)` returned "`error C2660: 'isalpha' : function does not take 0 arguments`". Have I made an error in coding?

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: I find VisualStudio's errors to be extremely obtuse. But my first thought is, did you remember to `#include <functional>`?

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: Also, you want to remove the `()` after `isalpha` in that expression. It should just be `std::bind2nd(isalpha,loc)`

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I included functional. I originally left out the () and that gave me the first error, slightly more expanded here: `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(320): error C2825: '_Fn2': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>          ..\..\..\..\..\..\..\t4\t4_mongoDB.cpp(324) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::binder2nd<_Fn2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fn2=int (int)
1>          ]`

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: I really have no idea how to interpret Visual Studio's errors. That sounds very bizarre.

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: I've figured it out. `std::bind2nd()` is worse than I thought. You can't just pass a function to it, you have to pass a `unary_function` or `binary_function` object. It looks like you can use the `std::ptr_fun()` function to convert a function pointer into one of these though, so `std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(isalpha), loc)` should work.

Comment: @Kevin I had tried (via Google search suggestions) but I get another perfectly clear MSVC 2010 error: `error C2039: 'first_argument_type' : is not a member of 'std::pointer_to_unary_function<_Arg,_Result,_Fn>'` Is it possible that the locale parameter doesn't play well with bind2nd?

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: Actually I think the problem now is disambiguating between the overloads of `isalpha()`. I'm trying to remember how you deal with that.

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: Success! The magic incantation is `std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun<char, const std::locale&, bool>(std::isalpha), loc)`. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Kevin `error C2451: conditional expression of type 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' is illegal` -- Are we getting a `bool` from this for find_if?

Comment: @Kevin i.e., `bool tf = std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun<char, const std::locale&, bool>(std::isalpha), loc);` gives `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::binder2nd<_Fn2>' to 'bool'`

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: No, the `std::bind2nd()` produces a `std::binder2nd<Op>` object, which is a function object (i.e. it has an `operator()`). Try `bool tf = std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun<char, const std::locale&, bool>(std::isalpha), loc)('c');` (note the addition of `('c')` on the end).

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: The error you have sounds like you used `field_name.begin()` or `field_name.end()` as the entire conditional expression for the `if` statement, although again, Visual Studio's errors are obtuse.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I see. I'm wondering then the source of `error C2451: conditional expression of type 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' is illegal` with `if ( find_if(field_name.begin(), field_name.end(),std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun<char, const std::locale&, bool>(std::isalpha), loc)) ) == field_name.end() )`

Comment: You've got an extra `)` in there. Specifically, the one that comes after `, loc))`

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: Here's a complete code example that compiles under Clang: https://gist.github.com/4273636

Comment: @Kevin -- sorry for the parens error. Odd MSVS didn't complain. Thought I'd check. Now it works perfectly and I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, you can use a lambda:

```
if (std::find_if(field_name.begin(), field_name.end(),
                 [&loc](char c)
                 {
                   return isalpha(c, loc);
                 }) == field_name.end())
{
  ...
}
```

In pre-C++11 you probably have to use something like boost::bind or boost::lambda to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 3):

In pre-C++11, you can wrap the `isalpha()` with an object that overrides the `()` operator, then use it as a predicate, if you don't want to use `std::bind...()` or boost, eg:

```
#include <locale>

struct isalphaloc
{
    const std::locale &_loc;

    isalphaloc(const std::locale &loc) : _loc(loc) {}

    bool operator(const char c) const
    {
        return isalpha(c, _loc);
    }
};
```

.

```
std::locale loc;
if ( find_if(field_name.begin(), field_name.end(), isalphaloc(loc)) == field_name.end() )
```